# Can a section in a Win32 PE contain a combination of both executable code, initialized data and unitialized data?

Tags: c++, windows, assembly, portable-executable

> Can a section in a Win32 PE contain a combination of both executable code, initialized data and unitialized data?

Is it possible for a section to contain any combination of code and (un)initialized data as section data, or can the section only contain one type of data?

It is the `Characteristics` field of the section header that has flags that determine its properties, but I'm uncertain whether it is possible to mix things up?

Below I've included the flags from the official PE documentation:

> `IMAGE_SCN_CNT_CODE 0x00000020` **The section contains executable code.**
>   `IMAGE_SCN_CNT_INITIALIZED_DATA 0x00000040` **The section contains**
>   **initialized data.** `IMAGE_SCN_CNT_UNINITIALIZED_ DATA 0x00000080` **The**
>   **section contains uninitialized data.**

Comment: Clearly the flag values support creating a section that has an arbitrary mix of all three flags.  That doesn't mean it is very likely you are going to run into such a file.  You can't get a warranty, custom VMs, loaders and obfuscators pull off weirdo tricks like this.

Comment: The flags are just claims of what the sections contain. Software can do anything it wants with the contents.