# Is code seen as initialized data in the Portable Executable format, and what exactly are the difference between initialized and unitialized data?

Tags: c++, windows, assembly, portable-executable

> Is code seen as initialized data in the Portable Executable (PE) format, and what exactly are the difference between initialized and unitialized data?

From previous experience, I see intialized data as something like a string or integer, but is executable code also refered to as initialized data in PE context?

Also, what exactly are the differences between initialized and unitialized data?

The documentation says:

> **Section Data**
>
> Initialized data for a section consists of simple blocks
>   of bytes. However, for sections that contain all zeros, the section
>   data need not be included.
>
> ...

Comment: Is there an ongoing exam or what? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39052762/can-a-section-in-a-win32-pe-contain-a-combination-of-both-executable-code-initi

Comment: What? Like you say, if you need specific strings or values in the program, those values need better be in the executable. If you just need a block of 10MB zeros, you don't have to store all those bytes in the file.

Comment: Code isn't data, it's code and has its own section. Also, it's pretty obvious that it's initialised since what else could initialise it?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I think the person who posted this question is using multiple accounts for some reason.

Comment: @RossRidge Could well be, did you flag for mod attention?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Multiple accounts are allowed here, so without evidence of something like voting fraud there's nothing for me to flag;.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every process consists of basically 4 portions of address space that are 
accessible to the process and one of them is the .Data section which is divided into :

1) **Initialized Read Only Data** : This contains the data elements 
that are initialized by the program and they are read only during the 
execution of the process.

2) **Initialized Read Write Data** : This contains the data elements 
that are initialized by the program and will be modified in the course of 
process execution.

3) **Uninitalized Data**  : This contains the elements are not 
initialized by the program and are set 0 before the processes executes. 
These can also be modified and referred as BSS(Block Started Symbol). The 
adv of such elements are, system doesn't have to allocate space in the 
program file for this area, b'coz it is initialized to 0 by OS before the 
process begins to execute.

> Is code seen as initialized data in the Portable Executable (PE) format

The code of any program can be found in .Text portion, it contains the actual  instructions to be executed, On many Operating Systems this is set to read only, similar to initialized Read Only Data.

> what exactly are the differences between initialized and unitialized data?

So the difference between them is in their value, the initialized data have an unique value set by the program before the process starts and can be Read Write or Read Only Data , in the other hand the uninitialized data value is set to 0 by the OS, you can take a look [here](http://csg.lbl.gov/pipermail/vxwexplo/2004-January/004166.html).

Amrane Abdelkader.

Comment: Thank you, but you forgot to mention whether code is initialized data?

Comment: i added the answer, hope you ll find it helpful.

Comment: It is just that the PE docs only mention section data as either initialized or uninitialized, so I guess code belongs to the first category then?

Comment: Right, it is like a the initialized Read Only Data but treated with special way.

Comment: This was just what I needed to know, thanks @AmraneAbdelkader.